# Why use char* to handle a union's address?

Tags: c

```
union a {
    struct a_header a_hdr;
    struct b        b_hdr;
};

bzero((char*)(&(&a->a_hdr)[1]), sizeof(struct b) - sizeof(struct a_header));
```

What does this call do? Where does `(char*)(&(&a->a_hdr)[1])` point to?

Comment: `char *` is often used as generic pointer holder for any buffer, it makes it easy to address things because  `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte in all POSIX systems and Windows, it is also 1 byte in most other architectures with very few exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation@Havenard so it will not change the result if I replace the generic pointer holder (char*) to (int*) or (void*)?

Comment: That recast probably doesn't matter at all, `bzero()` takes a `void*` as parameter which means it doesn't discriminate the type. Any pointer will work the same.

Comment: The `bzero` function is non-standard and obsolete. New code should use the standafrd `memset` instead. Both `bzero` and `memset` take an argument of type `void*`, so the cast is not even necessary (pointers are implicitly converted to `void*`). This looks like it could be very old (pre-ANSI) code. Prior to the 1989 C standard, `void*` didn't exist, `bzero` probably took an argument of type `char*`, and the cast was probably required. (And `memset` might not yet have been available in all implementations.)

Comment: That is true too. He's probably using something stupid old like TurboC. For some reason most colleges insist in using this fossil to teach C to their students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working under the assumption that `struct b` is larger than `struct a_header` (otherwise `sizeof(struct b) - sizeof(struct a_header)` would be zero or very large since `size_t` cannot be negative), this statement clears any bytes in `union a` that are used by `b_hdr` but *not* `a_hdr`.

Breaking down the expression:

```
&a->a_hdr
```

Given than `a` is a pointer to `union a`, this gets the address of the `a_hdr` field

```
(&a->a_hdr)[1]
```

This treats the above address as an array and gets the element at offset 1.  There is none, so this *would* be undefined behavior, but then we have:

```
&(&a->a_hdr)[1]
```

Since `a[b]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a + b)`, the above is the same as:

```
&(*(&a->a_hdr + 1))
```

The `&` and `*` adjacent to each other cancel each other out, so now you have:

```
&a->a_hdr + 1
```

So this points one element past the array of length 1 that is `a->a_hdr`.  It is this address that is passed to `bzero`.  The cast to `char *` is unnecessary since `bzero` takes a `void *` as its first parameter.

The second parameter:

```
sizeof(struct b) - sizeof(struct a_header)
```

Again, assuming `struct b` is bigger than `struct a_header`, this gives us the number of bytes that `struct b` is bigger by.  So the bytes used by `b_hdr` but *not* `a_hdr` are cleared.

To illustrate, suppose the `struct b` is 8 bytes and `struct a_header` is 4 bytes.  Then a `union a` would look like this:

```
---------------------------------
| X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |
---------------------------------
|           struct b            |
---------------------------------
|struct a_header|
-----------------
```

Where `X` is some unknown byte value.  After the above call to `bzero`, it looks like this:

```
---------------------------------
| X | X | X | X | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
---------------------------------
|           struct b            |
---------------------------------
|struct a_header|
-----------------
```

Comment: thanks, this explains a lot of things I was not clear about!! @dbush

Comment: @Hao Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess and say that struct b has a definition like,

```
struct b {
  struct a_header header;
  ... [other stuff]
}
```

The union allows you to access the member elements of the header more easily.

The line you have gets the address of the start of the [other stuff] portion of the struct b, and sets it to zero.

---

Breaking it down, starting from the inside

`&a->a_hdr` a is a pointer to the union of type union a (kinda confusing). This line gets the memory at the a_hdr portion of the union, this changes the type to struct a_header, then we get the address of it. The address here doesn't actually change, rather it is a safe way of casting the pointer to be of type struct a_header.

`&(&a->a_hdr)[1]` we treat the pointer to struct a_header as an array and get memory of the next element, then get the address of that memory. Essentially we have done `a + sizeof(struct a_header)`. This only makes sense if you know what is in the memory after struct a_header, either because you have an array or a struct like I placed in the above section.

`(char*)(&(&a->a_hdr)[1])` the cast changes the pointer type, it probably isn't necessary as most bzero implementations take a void pointer, but it doesn't hurt either.

`bzero((char*)(&(&a->a_hdr)[1]), sizeof(struct b) - sizeof(struct a_header))`

bzero is a function which sets a chunk of memory to zero, an alternative to memset. The second parameter sets the size, the subtraction strongly suggests that struct b contains as it's first member a variable of type struct a_header. The pointer manipulations in the first parameter skip over that element, the second parameter sets the size to be the remainder of struct b, bzero then clears this portion.

Comment: your guess to `struct b` is correct. Thanks@lod this gives a clear and good answer.